# How to compress/zip files in Microsoft Azure App Service console?

Tags: azure, download, command, compression, kudu

[image]

I know about the KUDU service in Microsoft Azure and it works great. However I have got very large data, which is greater than 3GB and it takes very long time to download and then upload to my new server. Is there a way to zip the data on Azure through command line and then do wget to download this data on new server. I have been doing this manually till now but it is taking it forever to download it to my PC first and then uploading to the server through FTP.

I am logged into Microsoft Azure App Service Console. I have tried compress, Compress-Archive and even zip command but nothing works. It says that famous internal and external command not found message.

`'compress' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

How could I compress these file on Azure console? Earliest help would be appreciated.

Or is there a way to install some compression tool on this server through command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the unzip utility is available, there's no zip tool.  One way around that is to upload the command line version of 7-Zip, it's a standalone .EXE file.

Comment: Thanks. I placed standalone exe of 7zip and it worked like a charm! 

Command: `FULL_PATH_TO\7za.exe a FULL_PATH_TO_NEW\zipfilename.zip FULL_PATH_TO\folder_to_zip`


Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

Now Windows and Kudu both support a native tar command, why not use that.

```
tar -cvzf my_archive.tar.gz input_dir
tar -xf my_archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: At least in my experience, because it simply does not work. E.g.:C:\home\site>tar -czf "C:\local\Temp\myarchive-11-8-23.tar.gz" wwwroot
tar (child): Cannot connect to C: resolve failed
tar
: C\:\\local\\Temp\\myarchive-11-8-23.tar.gz: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now